# How to convert datatype in json from number to string while keeping all object value as is typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

```
  {
      
      "data":[
      
     0: {"name":"IN00002","id": 2 },
     1: {"name":"IN00003","id": 3 }

      
      ]}
```

How to convert datatype in json from number to string while keeping all object value as is,
i want output as

```
{     
      "data":[
          
          0:{"name":"IN00002","id": "2" },
          1:{"name":"IN00003","id": "2" }
    
          
          ]}
```

I tried using this method but console.log gives me undefined

```
  this.jsonData =   Object.values(this.jsonData.data).forEach(function (key) {

    key.id = key.id.toString();
  
  });
console.log(this.jsonData);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the value of every field in your object that is a number to a string like this

```
function convertNumberFields(obj) {
    if (typeof obj !== 'object') {
        return
    }

    for (key in obj) {
        if (typeof obj[key] === 'number') {
            obj[key] = String(obj[key])
        } else {
            convertNumberFields(obj[key])
        }
    }
}

convertNumberFields(objectWithFieldsToConvert)
// now objectWithFieldsToConvert has no more number fields
```

Comment: i used it but give me   (RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded)

Comment: i think problem in my object structure   
      {
      "data":[
      
     0: {"name":"IN00002","id": 2 },
     1: {"name":"IN00003","id": 3 }

      
      ]}

Comment: this structure is not valid :{ "data":[ 0: {"name":"IN00002","id": 2 }, 1: {"name":"IN00003","id": 3 } ]}

Comment: I think you meant { "data":[ {"name":"IN00002","id": 2 }, {"name":"IN00003","id": 3 } ]}. Code works fine with this input.

Comment: thanks your function help me

Answer (score 0):

Assuming code within forEach method is correct:

```
this.jsonData =   Object.values(this.jsonData.data).forEach(...);
```

with the given data object will return an array within the array:

```
   [
     [
      0:{"name":"IN00002","id": 2 },
      1:{"name":"IN00003","id": 3 }         
     ]
  ]
```

Correct code is:

this.jsonData = Object.values(this.jsonData.data)**[0]**.forEach(...);

The code has multiple errors. It could be re-written as:

```
Object.values(this.jsonData.data).forEach(function (value, key) {
    this.jsonData[key].id = value.id.toString();
  });
console.log(this.jsonData);
```